# problems with html helper method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I can't figure out how to send a parameter from a dropdownlist to my model. Could someone please show me an example of how to do this?

Comment: Please post more details. Some sample code?

Answer (score 2):

As always you start by defining a model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public SelectList Items 
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
            }, "Value", "Text");
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // You will get the selected value inside model.SelectedValue here
        // => do something with it
        ....
    }
}
```

Strongly typed view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Items) %> 
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

Comment: thanks darin i think i didnt make question on the right way cuz dropdownlist take value from table on DB the problem was how to send the selected valut to the model as parameter thnx

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Affiliate affiliate = affiliateRepository.GetAffiliate(id);
            List<SelectListItem> StateList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            SelectListItem item;

            Dictionary<string, string> dictState = S127Global.Misc.getStates();


            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> k in dictState)
            {
                item = new SelectListItem();
                item.Text = k.Value;
                item.Value = k.Key;
                StateList.Add(item);
            }
            item = new SelectListItem();
            item.Text = " - Select State - ";
            item.Value = "";
            StateList.Insert(0, item);


            //create new select list with affiliate.state as the selected value in ViewData
            ViewData["State"] = new SelectList(StateList.AsEnumerable(), "Value", "Text",affiliate.State);
            return View(affiliate);
        }
```

code for view

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.State) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.DropDownList("State")%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State) %>
</div>
```